# Require Input in Masked Text Box

Tags: c#, tooltip, maskedtextbox

I have a masked text box (number of days) in a form that has to **always** have an integer inside. It **cannot** be blank when the user pressed the "OK" button on the form.

What I need is when the user pressed "OK", if the text box is not filled as it should be, a tool tip come up and show the user they need to enter information there before they can proceed.

What should I use for this? I'm guessing a variation of a Tool Tip and Masked Text Box, I just need a push in the right direction as I can't find the information anywhere.

Comment: Do you already have a masked textbox, or do you want to use one and don't know which control to use?

Answer (score 0):

use a regex control to validate the input and a required field validator. on the validation you could fill out a div with display:none then use jquery tooltip (or something like it) to display a tooltip with the information in that div. thats my first blush response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "")
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.maskedTextBox1, "Plz fill it");
    else
        this.errorProvider1.Dispose();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Validation controls provided by asp.net. You can set a required field validator and a Regular Expression Validator for the input field. Then, set the CausesValidation property of the input control to true. Validator controls provide error message labels which will be visible if the input value is invalid. For more information, you can visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx